# Selenium Grid 100 Instances

Tags: selenium, docker, protractor

I want to run an automatic test develop with Protractor in parallel on 50 instances of google chrome using selenium grid on an 8CPU machine and 16GB RAM. but the machine becomes very slow and the load averge exceeds 40.

There is someone who can help me to increase the instances of chrome on this machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Aerokube](http://aerokube.com/) guys solution, it works way faster than original Selenium Grid:

- [Selenoid](https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid) - Go implementation of original Selenium hub code. It
  is using Docker to launch browsers.
- [GGR](https://github.com/aerokube/ggr) - A lightweight load
  balancer used to create big Selenium clusters

Comment: +1 Selenoid is your friend for that. Check my comment at https://github.com/zalando/zalenium/issues/116#issuecomment-305514067